# Can someone explain me how this function for removing duplicate values in array work?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have been looking for a javascript function that remove duplicate values in array.
I found this function:

```
function removeDuplicateElement(arrayName)
{
    var newArray=new Array();
    label:for(var i=0; i<arrayName.length;i++ )
    {   
        for(var j=0; j<newArray.length;j++ )
        {
            if(newArray[j]==arrayName[i]) 
            continue label;
        }
        newArray[newArray.length] = arrayName[i];
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

which is what i need. 
Can someone explain me how this function actually work and for what that 'label:' is?
I cant understand the logic of this code and if someone can give me an explanation it will be great. 10x

Comment: I've never seen that label syntax before (neat!).  the code says "for each element in the old array, check to see if it exists in the new array... if so, skip it, copy it into a new array (if we didn't skip it)"

Comment: That inner for loop is not needed. Instead: `if ( newArray.indexOf( arrayName[i] ) > -1 ) {... }`

Comment: Also, notice how the function doesn't remove the duplicates from the array, but returns a *new* array that doesn't contain duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JavaScript, you can specify a `label:` as a location to jump to in a `continue`  or `break` statement. So when the `continue` is reached, the iteration returns to the outer for loop instead of the inner loop where it resides (which would be the default behavior of `continue`)

Basically, this function works by making a new array `newArray` (not modifying the old one) and looping over every element in the original array. It adds the element from the original array to the `newArray` if not already found. It determines if it already is present in `newArray` by looping over that it for each iteration of the old array's loop and looking for the matching value `arrayName[i]`

```
function removeDuplicateElement(arrayName)
{
    // Declares a new array to hold the deduped values
    var newArray=new Array();
    // Loops over the original array
    // label: here defines a point for the continue statement to target
    label:for(var i=0; i<arrayName.length;i++ )
    {   
        // Loops over the new array to see if the current value from the old array
        // already exists here
        for(var j=0; j<newArray.length;j++ )
        {
            // The new array already has the current loop val from the old array
            if(newArray[j]==arrayName[i]) 
            // So it returns to the outer loop taking no further action 
            // This advances the outer loop to its next iteration
            continue label;
        }
        // Otherwise, the current value is added to the new array
        newArray[newArray.length] = arrayName[i];
    }
    // The new deduped array is returned from the function
    return newArray;
}
```

For more information on the function of the `continue` in this context, [have a look at the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue).

Answer (score 1):

The function loops through all the elements in the existing array and adds them to the new array if they're not already in it. The `label` allows the inner loop to use the `continue` statement to continue with the next iteration of the *outer* loop rather than the next iteration of the inner loop. A regular `continue` would just repeat the inner loop, which is what would happen anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify that a bit with ES5 methods:

```
function dumpDupes ( arr ) {
    var arr2 = [];
    arr.forEach(function ( item ) {
        if ( arr2.indexOf( item ) === -1 ) arr2.push( item );
    });
    return arr2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI [Sizzle's method](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/master/sizzle.js#L784) is faster:

```
function dedupe(array) {
    array.sort();
    for(var i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i-1] == array[i])
            array.splice(i--, 1);
    }

    return array;
}
```

Although I was actually tweaking this to see if I could speed it up any on jsperf.com - this is actually faster than either:

```
function dedupeManyDupes(array) {
    array.sort();
    var l = array.length;
    for(var i = 1; i < l; i++) {
        if (array[i-1] == array[i]) {
            var dupe = array[i];
            var mark = i;
            for(i++; i < l && array[i] == dupe; i++)
            {}
            var snip = i - mark;
            array.splice(mark, snip);
            i -= snip;
            l -= snip;
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

http://jsperf.com/js-dedupe-small
http://jsperf.com/js-dedupe-large
http://jsperf.com/js-dedupe-many-dupes

http://jsfiddle.net/b9chris/fLBTv/